# How to list the checkins into a particular branch

Tags: perforce

In perforce, how can I generate a report for the checkins made by certain users into a particular branch.

Answer (score 3):

p4 changes -u username //path/to/branch/...

You'll need to run the command multiple times, once for each user of interest.

If you're just getting started in writing these sorts of scripts and tools on top of Perforce,  you may want to pick your favorite scripting language, and start getting familiar with the Perforce extensions for programming in that particular scripting language: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/index.html